# How does the SE system choose accounts for automatic association?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, association, linked-accounts

Users with >200 rep on any SE site automatically get a +100 bonus when associating with another SE site.  The association process is handled automatically for existing SE users who open accounts on SE sites they haven't used before.

How does the system decide which existing account to associate with?  Does the system always choose an account with >200 rep if such an account is available?

(For those with too much time who want to know the full rationale behind this question, read about nine minutes worth of the chat transcript starting [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/121189).  In a nutshell, [Diago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/132480/diago) said so.)

Comment: In my defense. I made an assumption after creating an account and trying to understand the process. As far as I can see the association and bonus is done on your Area51 rep if it is a site in Beta.

Answer (score 1):

From the [blog announcement](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/), it associates your account with all eligible accounts (share the same OpenId) as well as:

> 1.Grant you a **+100** reputation bonus on the *current* site, as long as you have at least **+200** reputation on *any* site in our network. So you’re not treated like a newbie on every new site we launch.
>
> 2.Copies your profile from the network site where you have the *highest* reputation, to the current site.
>
> 3.Locate any of your questions that were migrated to this site and make you own them again. It was impossible for you to own them prior to this point, because you didn’t even have an account on the current site!

<s>When it comes to multiple accounts on the same OpenId that aren't all associated, it targets your highest reputation first (probably to perform point 2 and also check for point 2), and grabs all accounts that are associated with that specific account. This is what I experienced when I created my Gaming account.</s>

Haha, wow, that's crazy. It seems to progress in order of site creation. I checked myself, as well as one user who had dissociated accounts at the time of association. So it'll first check Stack Overflow, and associate with that if you have one. It'll then grab the accounts associated with that. I would expect that if it didn't find a Stack Overflow account, it'll then advance to Server Fault, then Super User, then Meta, then Area 51.

Comment: Interesting. We have a case where this didn't happen on one of the Beta sites.

Comment: @Diago Hum. I'll double check my user history on Gaming, then. That'll show the real process.

Comment: @Diago And if my statement is still wrong after that edit, then the easiest answer is to prod one of the diamonds on that Beta (or a dev, if that site doesn't have pro tems yet) and ask them to check the User History for that user. It'll clearly show the order for association.

Comment: Thanks. It was one of the reasons for posting here. The user I mentioned in question has got enough rep on SO, but never got the associations bonus.