# How do you change your display name on a per-site meta?

Tags: support, association, display-names, linked-accounts, per-site-meta

When I signed up for the Gaming SE, my account was auto-associated with my SOFU/MSO accounts.  On SOFU, my name is Lord Torgamus; on MSO, it's Popular Demand.  The auto-association process chose to use Popular Demand to populate my Gaming profile.  (I'm not sure how MSO was chosen; that's the topic of [a separate Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62265/how-does-the-se-system-choose-accounts-for-automatic-association).)

Unfortunately, I don't want my name to be Popular Demand there; I want it to be Lord Torgamus.  I disassociated my accounts and reassociated all of them except MSO*; no effect.  So I manually changed my "parent" Gaming name to Lord Torgamus with the "edit" link in my profile; that worked, but didn't propagate to Meta Gaming.

All of my accounts use the same OpenID, though MSO has a different e-mail address for gravatar purposes.

**The exception is Server Fault; when I try to reassociate my SF account, I get a popup "user Id 10907 already associated with another account."  My Gaming user ID is 197, and my SF ID is 10907; my SF account is showing that it's not associated with anything at all.  Not sure if this is related, or a separate bug.*

What can I do to change my Meta Gaming name?

Comment: The potential of [some manner of account association desync](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56447/why-arent-some-users-listed-as-participating-in-the-beta-on-area-51/56479#56479) was also tested, and did not fix the name, in case anyone thought about that avenue.

Answer (score 2):

This was discussed on the [WebApps meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376/the-username-on-meta-is-not-editable-and-does-not-reflect-the-username-on-the-par).

> In the (recent) past we only synchronized reputation between the child-meta and parent site on the hour. Total profile syncs required a login/logout, as you discovered.
>
> This has been changed. Now if you update your profile it will be pulled down to the child-meta site, though it may take an hour or so for it to occur.

Comment: My update was performed something like eight days ago; well over an hour, in any case.