# Why didn't programmers SE site associate my account with all the other sites?

Tags: bug, linked-accounts

I've been on the SO trilogy sites since beta.  I log into each one with the same OpenID as always.  But, this time for Programmers SE, it does not associate and I didn't get my free 100 rep.

When I go to my Programmers SE profile / Accounts tab, it shows I'm associated with answers.onstartups.com and nothing else.  When I click "Associate with X" for any of the other sites listed, it pops up with "User id 3347 already associated with another account".

I looked at my Onstartsups profile and it's the same story as Programmers.

I looked at my SO, SF, and SU accounts and everything's nicely linked up except for Programmers and Onstartups.  When I try associating, I get the same error.

Can this be fixed by me or a mod?

Comment: There's a _slight_ chance that this is related to my [earlier bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63154/how-do-you-change-your-display-name-on-a-per-site-meta); I say this only because I got unexpected "already associated" weirdness too.

Comment: same thing here, i've had weird behaviors with the associated accounts

Answer (score 0):

According to your [list of accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/2407/spoulson?tab=accounts), your Programmers account is properly associated with the rest of them.