# My Area 51 reputation is different from my Area 51 discuss reputation

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51, per-site-meta

At time of writing this question, my [Area 51 reputation](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/153232/john?tab=stats) is 222, while my [Area 51 discussion reputation](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/153232/john?__=1210849824) is 207. It has been this way for weeks.

I thought that Area 51 discussion was a meta site for Area 51, and therefore users should have the same amount of reputation on both of them. Has my Area 51 discussion account gotten out-of-sync with my Area 51 account? Or is there some other reason why my two accounts have a reputation that don't match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Meta rep should sync with main site periodically. I forced that sync for your account and now your A51 Discuss reputation matches Area 51.

---

Turns out that the service that runs scheduled tasks on A51 meta has been broken for a while...

> [image: log screenshot]

Spot anything weird in the URL? It's no longer discuss.area51, but rather area51.meta. Nick Craver fixed up the scheduler config, and all scheduled tasks should be running correctly again.

We have plans to replace the current scheduler with a service that doesn't fail quite so silently, but there's no (•_•) ... ( •_•)>⌐■-■ ... (⌐■_■) schedule for it being deployed yet.

Comment: How often does this sync take place? My last reputation change on Area 51 was 4 days ago. And judging by my reputation history there, it hasn't synced in a month. No need to force-sync my account BTW. I'd rather leave it as it is, if that makes it easier for the devs to investigate.

Comment: @S.L.Barth [up to one hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63154/how-do-you-change-your-display-name-on-a-per-site-meta/63156#63156)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Also on Area 51? Area 51 has always been a special case.

Comment: @S.L.Barth it's old, but so is that synchronization code. So actually it's likely one hour always, as it says "we only synchronized reputation between the child-meta and parent site on the hour" - and Area 51 still got that old code probably. Adam can confirm for sure though.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Shadow Wizard is right - it's supposed to be hourly. Something's definitely off, though. I started looking into it last week, but didn't see any immediately obvious errors. I'll pick this back up.

Comment: @AdamLear OK, good luck finding it!

Comment: @S.L.Barth check the edit, you're going to like it. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for the notification. Typical, isn't it? Once you know the cause of the bug, it makes perfect sense - but until then... Well, anyway, good work by Adam!

Comment: @S.L.Barth hehe right! And I should have said it before: https, it's always https... ;-)